# Is it possible to blacklist certain built-in functions from being emitted during compilation?

Tags: c, gcc

In a few projects I explicitly do not link against libgcc, so some things are missing.

Under certain circumstances this can lead to undefined reference failures for functions such as `__gnu_thumb1_case_uqi` when specifying `-Os` optimization for example.

How can I prevent gcc from emitting these functions during compilation?

Comment: I believe it is impossible to completely avoid emissions of calls to libgcc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

> ```
> -fno-builtin
> -fno-builtin-function
> ```
>
> > Don’t recognize built-in functions that do not begin with ‘`__builtin_`’ as prefix. See Other built-in functions provided by GCC, for details of the functions affected, including those which are not built-in functions when `-ansi` or `-std` options for strict ISO C conformance are used because they do not have an ISO standard meaning.
>
> <sub>[GCC Online Docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options)</sub>

However, if you `#include` header files with macros that expand into calls to GCC builtin functions, you can only stop that by not including those headers. If you are not linking with the standard libraries, you also probably do not want to include from the standard header files.